# How to use Media Player In Android?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have created demo for media player in Android.I'm facing the problem while start to run my application.When my app is run song is playing but not playing the full song it just start and immediately finish means it just start activity and immediately goes to resume() state.And when song is get over the i again restart my activity song is not playing from beginning it start from middle.I'm facing this problem last 1 week and i don't understand how to solve it .Please can any one help me.Here is my code.Thanks in advanced.

```
public class Audio_Activity extends Activity 
{
    private MediaPlayer mp = null;
    PhoneStateListener phListener;
    int length;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    ImageView imgVw;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.audio);
        init();
        imgVw.setImageResource(R.raw.teddy_two);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences. Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();

         mp=MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.issaq_tera_by_vishu);
         Log.e("Song is playing","in  Mediya Player ");

         mp.start();
         mp.setLooping(false);
         System.out.println("Media Plyer Is Start !!!");
         prefsEdit.putBoolean("mediaplaying", true);
         prefsEdit.commit();
         btnChapter.setEnabled(false);

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.stop();
                 System.out.println("Media Plyer Is Complete !!!");
                //mp.release();
                prefsEdit.putBoolean("mediaplaying", false);
                prefsEdit.commit();
                btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
                System.out.println("Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!");
            }
        });


        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener()
          {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)

                {
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) 

                    {

                        if(mp!=null)

                        {
                            setPlayerButton(true, false, true);

                            if(mp.isPlaying())
                            { 

                                mp.pause();

                            }
                        }

                    } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

                    } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {

                    }
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                }
            };

            TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

             if(mgr != null) 
             {

                 mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
             }


    }


    private void setPlayerButton(Boolean play, Boolean pause, Boolean stop){
        btnStartStop.setEnabled(play);
        if(play==true)
            btnStartStop.setEnabled(true);
        else
            btnStartStop.setEnabled(false);

    }



     @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
     {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 

      }


     @Override
     public void onPause()
     {
         super.onPause();

          SharedPreferences. Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();
          boolean isPlaying=prefs.getBoolean("mediaplaying",false);
          if(isPlaying)
          {
              int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
              Log.e("Current ","Position -> " + position);
              prefsEdit.putInt("mediaPosition", position);
              prefsEdit.commit();
          }
     }


     @Override
        protected void onResume() 
        {
            super.onResume();

            System.out.println("Activity is Resume !!!");

            boolean isPlaying=prefs.getBoolean("mediaplaying",false);
            if(isPlaying)
            {
                  int position = prefs.getInt("mediaPosition", 0);
                  mp.seekTo(position);
                  mp.start();

            }

        }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        super.onStop();

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
        { 
            if(mp!= null)
            {
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.pause();
                     System.out.println("Media Player is Pause/Stop click on Back button on Emulator!!!");

                }
            }
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the starting from middle of the song problem is because you store the current progress of song in `SharedPreferences` and then at `onResume()` you start the player from the progressed position  that stored at `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to register for `OnPreapredListener` via `MediaPlayer.setOnPreaparedListener` and after preparation you start your media playback.

Official guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code.

```
        void play() {

         mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
            getApplicationContext(), R.raw.keytone);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();

                   }
  private void pause()

     {

         mediaPlayer.release();

       }
```